# What the difference between classes with space and no space in css, what the use of multiple classes with no space

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class

I am making an accordion using CSS, the below is my use of CSS class without space. I use this to eliminate the animation of padding during slideDown and slideUp effect

```
.acc_container.block{
    padding: 20px; 
}
```

since it stated out that padding is 20 pixels but when i check it seems like no padding at all!!

instead, i need to add this in order to let my padding works

```
.acc_container. block{
    padding: 20px; 
}
```

(with space)

So what's the difference between the class in CSS with and without a space?

This is all my HTML, jQuery with CSS code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    font: 15px normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}
.container {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
h2.acc_trigger {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    background: url(h2_trigger_a.gif) no-repeat;
    height: 46px;
    line-height: 46px;
    width: 500px;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: normal;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 0 0 50px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
h2.active {
    background-position: left bottom;
}
.acc_container {
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 500px;
    clear: both;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
.acc_container.block {
    padding: 20px;
}
.block {
    padding: 20px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script> type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
       $('.acc_container').hide();    $('.acc_trigger:first').addClass('active').next().show();
       $('.acc_trigger').click(function(){
        if($(this).next().is(':hidden')) 
        {
           $('.acc_trigger').removeClass('active').next().slideUp();
     $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown();
        }  

       return false;    });

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="acc_trigger">Web Design and Development</a></h2>
    <div class="acc_container">
        <div class="block">
            <h3>Need A website?</h3>
            <p>Consequat te olim letalis premo ad hos olim odio olim indoles ut 
            venio iusto. Euismod, sagaciter diam neque antehabeo blandit, jumentum 
            transverbero luptatum. Lenis vel diam praemitto molior facilisi facilisi 
            suscipere abico, ludus, at. Wisi suscipere nisl ad capto comis esse, 
            autem genitus. Feugiat immitto ullamcorper hos luptatum gilvus eum. 
            Delenit patria nunc os pneum acsi nulla magna singularis proprius autem 
            exerci accumsan.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h2 class="acc_trigger">Logo/ Corporate Identity</h2>
    <div>
        class=&quot;acc_container&quot;&gt;
        <div class="block">
            <h3>Need a Logo?</h3>
            <p>Consequat te olim letalis premo ad hos olim odio olim indoles ut 
            venio iusto. Euismod, sagaciter diam neque antehabeo blandit, jumentum 
            transverbero luptatum. Lenis vel diam praemitto molior facilisi facilisi 
            suscipere abico, ludus, at. Wisi suscipere nisl ad capto comis esse, 
            autem genitus. Feugiat immitto ullamcorper hos luptatum gilvus eum. 
            Delenit patria nunc os pneum acsi nulla magna singularis proprius autem 
            exerci accumsan. </p>
            <p>Consequat te olim letalis premo ad hos olim odio olim indoles ut 
            venio iusto. Euismod, sagaciter diam neque antehabeo blandit, jumentum 
            transverbero luptatum. Lenis vel diam praemitto molior facilisi facilisi 
            suscipere abico, ludus, at. Wisi suscipere nisl ad capto comis esse, 
            autem genitus. Feugiat immitto ullamcorper hos luptatum gilvus eum. 
            Delenit patria nunc os pneum acsi nulla magna singularis proprius autem 
            exerci accumsan. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h2 class="acc_trigger">Search Engine Optimization</a></h2>
    <div class="acc_container">
        <div class="block">
            <h3>Need to be heard</h3>
            <p>Consequat te olim letalis premo ad hos olim odio olim indoles ut 
            venio iusto. Euismod, sagaciter diam neque antehabeo blandit, jumentum 
            transverbero luptatum. Lenis vel diam praemitto molior facilisi facilisi 
            suscipere abico, ludus, at. Wisi suscipere nisl ad capto comis esse, 
            autem genitus. Feugiat immitto ullamcorper hos luptatum gilvus eum. 
            Delenit patria nunc os pneum acsi nulla magna singularis proprius autem 
            exerci accumsan.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`.className. anotherClassName` is invalid selector, so it will be ignored by browsers. Space itself () is a [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors).

So you probably ask what's the difference between `.classA .classB` and `.classA.classB` selectors.

First selector will match any element with class `classB` that's placed within element with class `classA`, eg.:

```
<div class="classA">
  <p>
    Hello World!
    <span class="classB">this text will be matched by first selector</span>
    Lorem ipsum!
  </p>
</div>
```

Second selector will match any elements with both, `classA` and `classB` classes, eg.:

```
<p class="classA">This won't be matched</p>
<p class="classA classB classC classD">But this will be</p>
```

Comment: but as you see, why can i use .classA.classB without having and element with both class?Thanks for your explaination

Comment: You're using `.classA.classB` selector and rules are applied to the element `<div class="classA">`? That shouldn't ever happen. Class selector is very well supported by all major browsers (IE6 had some problems with that). Please put entire code that illustrate the issue.

Comment: does <div class="classA"><div class="ClassB">content</div></div> considered as <div class="classA classB"> ? And how you put grey section on the code in the comment thanks

Comment: No, they're not. First code is element `div` with class `classA` that has **a child element** (another `div`) and that child has a class `classB`. The second code is a single element `div` with two classes `classA` and `classB`. About grey section... SO provides simple markup for "inline code". Use [backquotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/`#Technical_notes) to wrap your code: ` code-here `

Comment: Good answer, and I think this may further clarify @Crozin's answer:

The first selector (.classA .classB) will not work on <div class="classA classB">...</div> 

(...but as mentioned by Crozin, will work on '<div class="classA"><div class="classB">...</div></div>)

Answer (score 1):

It´s all about addressing the right element the right way **AND** taking into account the fact that older versions of Internet Explorer don´t recognize multiple classes on an element and will only use the last one.

Suppose your html is:

```
<div class="one two">some content</div>
```

older versions of IE will only apply class `.two`.

However, in modern browsers you can access it like:

```
.one {
}
```

or

```
.two {
}
```

or

```
.one.two {
}
```

The last one is obviously the most specific.

By the way, something like:

```
.acc_container. block{ padding: 20px; }
```

is bound to lead to problems as there is no html element called `block` and `.acc_container.` is not a valid class name I think...

Answer (score 0):

`.acc_container.block` - this one means that both "acc_container" and "block" are applied to element
Like 
    `<div class="acc_container block another-class">`

`.acc_container .block` - means: each element with class "block" inside element with class "acc_container"

For example: 
`<div class="acc_container">  <p class="block">...`

Comment: can u explain that in my html code,there is no something like 2 thing applied to the same element, but why i can add the .acc_container.block to my css?

Comment: Looks like these 2 classes applied via JavaScript code. So you don't see both applied in the HTML source